# PyQt QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using PyQt5 on Python 3.6 for 64-bit Windows. When I call `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('MYSQL')` and run my utility, it shows up with this error message:

`QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QP
SQL QPSQL7`

This confuses me since according to the error message, the `QMYSQL` driver is loaded. I installed PyQt through the default installer, so the MySQL plugin should be installed. Has anyone else experienced this problem or does someone know the cause of this?

Comment: Put MySQL drivers in the directory sqldrivers in your executable's directory.

Comment: This has *just* started happening to me too under Linux, having always worked without problem till today....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It said driver available but you need to rebuid a new Mysql driver base on Qt Source code and Mysql Library.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue for me with Windows 10.
I didn't investigate much about making the QMYSQL driver available in Windows 10, but here is a workaround :

- use QODBC driver (`QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')`)
- db.setDatabaseName(My_ODBC_source)

"My_ODBC_source" has to be created. On Windows 10:

1. Install Mysql ODBC 5.x ANSI Driver (32 bits) ([download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html))
2. create a new user or machine ODBC data source named "My_ODBC_source"
   (see [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2.html)) You must provide ip address or mysql server name, user, password.So it does not have to be provided in your pyqt code.